# Sum of orthogonal univariate Gaussians yields multivariate Gaussian

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

Define the multivariate Gaussian PDF being proportional to $ e^{-\pi ||x||^2}.$

In a paper I'm reading is written that

> This distribution can be expressed as the sum of $n$ orthogonal 1-dimensional Gaussian distributions...

But this statement is not clear to me. First of all, what do they mean with the *sum* of distributions? I understand that if we add up univariate Gaussians we end up again with a **univariate** Gaussian, but I don't understand how to get a multivariate distribution from the "sum" of univariate ones.

Secondly, I don't understand what they mean with *orthogonal* (in general, I do not know what does it mean for a set of distributions to be orthogonal, maybe orthogonal with respect to certain inner product?).

I already spent enough time surfing the web in order to get information about this, without any concrete result I'm afraid. Any help will be highly appreciated!

---

**Context and Background**

The paper I'm reading is [worst-case to average-case reductions based on gaussian measures](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/papers/average.pdf), and the statement is on top of page 8. About my background, I don't have any previous knowledge on normal distributions, and I'm having a tough fight in order to learn all these topics by my own.